# GKE: Docker login alway succeeds, but push does not work even with valid credentials

Tags: docker, oauth-2.0, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, docker-registry

I have a GKE cluster running in GCE, I was able to build + tag an image derived from ubuntu:16.04:

```
/ # docker images
REPOSITORY                          TAG                 IMAGE ID            
CREATED             SIZE
eu.gcr.io/my-project/ubuntu-gcloud   latest              a723e43228ae        7 minutes ago       347MB
ubuntu                              16.04               ebcd9d4fca80        7 days ago          118MB
```

First I try to log in to registry (as documented in GKE docs)  
`` docker login -u oauth2accesstoken -p `curl -s "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"|awk -F\" "{ print \$4 }"` eu.gcr.io` ``

And then the `docker push` command fails:

```
# docker push eu.gcr.io/my-project/ubuntu-gcloud
The push refers to a repository [eu.gcr.io/my-project/ubuntu-gcloud]
a3a6893ab23f: Preparing
6e390fa7d62c: Preparing
22b8fccbaf84: Preparing
085eeae7a10b: Preparing
b29983dd2306: Preparing
33f1a94ed7fc: Waiting
b27287a6dbce: Waiting
47c2386f248c: Waiting
2be95f0d8a0c: Waiting
2df9b8def18a: Waiting
denied: Unable to create the repository, please check that you have access to do so.
```

The token should be valid, in another instance I'm able to `gcloud whatever` with it; the service account has 'Editor' role on the project.

The weirdest part is when I do `docker login` with obviously invalid credentials

```
misko@MacBook ~ $ docker login -u oauth2accesstoken -p somethingverystupidthatisreallynotmypasswordortoken123 eu.gcr.io
Login Succeeded
```

login always succeeds.

What shall I do to successfully `docker push` to gcr.io?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
gcloud docker -- push eu.gcr.io/my-project/ubuntu-gcloud
```

If you want to use regular docker commands, update your docker configuration with GCR credentials:

```
gcloud docker -a
```

Then you can build and push docker images like this:

```
docker build -t eu.gcr.io/my-project/ubuntu-gcloud .
docker push eu.gcr.io/my-project/ubuntu-gcloud
```

Comment: Well that's an egg-chicken problem - I'm building image of Ubuntu + gcloud for building and pushing my own docker images. For the initial push of the baked image, I need to push without gcloud. I can think of 1024 workarounds, I'm just wondering why this is so unclear...

Comment: Btw `gcloud preview`: `ERROR: (gcloud) Invalid choice: 'preview'.`

Comment: @Misko looks like `preview` is deprecated now. [Release notes](https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/RELEASE_NOTES) say that `gcloud preview docker` moved to `gcloud docker`.

Comment: but honestly I don't get why you cannot use gcloud

Comment: ~1hour ago I started using `gcloud docker push` but ending up with `Unable to create the repository, please check that you have access to do so.`. I'm investigating on that; I'm pretty sure my service account has Owner perms (!) but still no luck

Comment: @Misko how about `gcloud docker -a` and then `docker push`?

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: @Misko then I believe it is really auth problem not how you are pushing the image

Comment: Okay, I found out and it's crazy. I'm using DinD for image building, so two containers. If I do the same (docker login + curl stuff) in the `docker:dind` container, push works. If I do this thing in the build container, it fails.

Comment: Meh, it does not. You wait until progressbars go 100% and then get `denied: Access denied.`. :hangman: